# Need to cat multiple files in TCL

Tags: append, tcl, cat

I want to cat or merge 2 files together. Is it better to use exec cat or append?

Below is my cat script but doesnt seem to be working.

```
set infile [open "$dir/1.txt" w+]

puts $infile "set a 1"
puts $infile "set b 2"

exec /bin/cat "$dir/1.txt $dir2/ABC1.sh" > final.sh

close $infile
```

Comment: I'd expect to see a "file not found" error from cat with `"$dir/1.txt $dir2/ABC1.sh"` being quoted as one word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet "doesn't seem to be working" means you're only seeing the contents of `$dir2/ABC1.sh` in `final.sh` (Or maybe seeing part of what you're writing to `$fir1/1.txt`, not all data). If so, you're running into buffering problems, trying to read `$dir/1.txt` before closing or flushing `infile` like you are. The data hasn't been written to the underlying file yet.

For concatenating multiple files into one, instead of relying on an external program like `cat` (There might be problems with how you're quoting the arguments to `exec`, too...), I'd use the various routines from the [fileutil](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/md/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.md) module from tcllib to do it in pure `tcl`:

```
package require fileutil
fileutil::writeFile final.sh [fileutil::cat -- $dir/1.txt $dir2/ABC1.sh]
```

If you have big files and don't want to hold them all in memory (Or don't want to/can't install tcllib), [`chan copy`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/chan.htm#M21) will also work:

```
set outfile [open final.sh w]
foreach file [list $dir/1.txt $dir2/ABC1.sh] {
    set sourcefile [open $file r]
    chan copy $sourcefile $outfile
    close $sourcefile
}
close $outfile
```

Comment: Yes,  I am only seeing the content of $dir2/ABC1.sh in the final.sh.

Comment: The version with `chan copy` is good and correct.